# Convert JSON to object and then back to JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON that is not bound to any schema.
I need to convert one of its line to JSON array in C#.

This is an input JSON example with the code:

```
// Let's change an eWay-type JSON to an anonymous object
string eWayData = @"{ ""originalMessageId"": """", ""templateId"": ""33483"", ""email"": ""whatever@domain.com"", ""extFields"": { ""customerName"": ""Hans-Jurgen Gumby"", ""customerAddressLine1"": ""21 Test Drive"", ""customerAddressLine2"": """", ""customerAddressCity"": ""Manchester"", ""customerContactNumber"": ""0123456789"", ""items"": ""Senses Sweet & Joyful Hand Wash - 250ml|1|£1.00|202305^Senses Orange Twist Hand Wash - 250ml|1|£1.00|202305^Senses Lavender Calm Hand Wash|2|£2.00|202305^Power Stay 24 Hour Longwear Foundation SPF10|1|£12.50|202305^310N Medium Beige|1|-^Black Suede Hot Eau de Toilette - 75ml|1|£10.00|202305"", ""orderTotal"": ""£26.50"", ""deliveryCharge"": ""£0.00"", ""orderNumber"": ""123456789"", ""couponCode"": """", ""promotions"": """", ""parentOrderId"": """", ""subject"": ""Your order has been shipped"", ""fromName"": ""My Notifications"", ""fromEmail"": ""notification@whatever.domain.com"" } }";

// Let's see if it has items
JObject eWayJson = JObject.Parse(eWayData);
JObject extFields = (JObject)eWayJson["extFields"];

// Do we have this field?
if (extFields["items"] != null)
{
    List<string> records = extFields["items"]
        .ToString()
        .Split(new char[] { '^' })
        .ToList();
    List<List<string>> fields = new List<List<string>>();
    records.ForEach(x => fields.Add(x.Split(new char[] { '|' }).ToList()));

    extFields.Property("items").Value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fields);
}
```

As you can see there is a field called "item" that contains some non-JSON conform data. It should been an array, but it is a string, separated by | and ^ characters. First I need to split up to list of items and then every item to list of fields. The end result should be something like this:

```
"items": [
["Senses Sweet & Joyful Hand Wash - 250ml","1","£1.00","202305"],
["Senses Orange Twist Hand Wash - 250ml","1","£1.00","202305"],
["Senses Lavender Calm Hand Wash","2","£2.00","202305"],
["Power Stay 24 Hour Longwear Foundation SPF10","1","£12.50","202305"],
["310N Medium Beige","1","-"],["Black Suede Hot Eau de Toilette - 75ml","1","£10.00","202305"]
],
```

so an array of arrays. My code works ok, except for one little problem: instead of what I show above, I got the following:

```
"items": "[[\"Senses Sweet & Joyful Hand Wash - 250ml\",\"1\",\"£1.00\",\"202305\"],[\"Senses Orange Twist Hand Wash - 250ml\",\"1\",\"£1.00\",\"202305\"],[\"Senses Lavender Calm Hand Wash\",\"2\",\"£2.00\",\"202305\"],[\"Power Stay 24 Hour Longwear Foundation SPF10\",\"1\",\"£12.50\",\"202305\"],[\"310N Medium Beige \",\"1\",\"-\"],[\"Black Suede Hot Eau de Toilette - 75ml\",\"1\",\"£10.00\",\"202305\"]]",
```

The array of arrays is represented as string, so it's not really an array.

Very important that the JSON cannot be mapped to a C# object, and then converted back, because the fields can change from case to case, hence I'm trying to use this anonymous-kind of approach.

I know that it could be done quite easily in Node.js for example, but I need to do in C#, and .NET 4.7. How can I overcome on this, what could I use instead of simply assigning the value to the items property or how should I tell the code to understand that this is a JSON array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you serialize c# object you convert it to a json string, but you need to convert it to JArray. Use FromObject instead of serialize

```
    JObject eWayJson = JObject.Parse(eWayData);
    var items = (string) eWayJson["extFields"]["items"];
    if (items != null)
    {
        var records = items.Split(new char[] { '^' }).ToList();

        var fields = new List<List<string>>();

        records.ForEach(x => fields.Add(x.Split(new char[] { '|' }).ToList()));
    
        eWayJson["extFields"]["items"] = JArray.FromObject(fields);

        eWayData = eWayJson.ToString();
    }
```